# Double array used in trie tree

Tags: c, trie

I tried to understand trie tree implement by double array tree from [this link](http://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html).

1. On collisions, it should relocate. And from pseudo code, why it should update `check[base[base[s] + c] + d]` and `base[b+c]` also?

Can anyone explain it in simple language?

```pascal
Procedure Relocate(s : state; b : base_index)
{ Move base for state s to a new place beginning at b }
begin
    foreach input character c for the state s
    { i.e. foreach c such that check[base[s] + c]] = s }
    begin
        check[b + c] := s;     { mark owner }
        base[b + c] := base[base[s] + c];     { copy data }
        { the node base[s] + c is to be moved to b + c;
          Hence, for any i for which check[i] = base[s] + c, update check[i] to b + c }
        foreach input character d for the node base[s] + c
        begin
            check[base[base[s] + c] + d] := b + c
        end;
        check[base[s] + c] := none     { free the cell }
    end;
    base[s] := b
end
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: how can i know if relocate,what will be update?

Comment: i'd like to know how do author know base[b+c],check[base[base[s]+c]+d] need to be updated,and what check[base[base[s] + c] + d] means?